# type 'LabeledGlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>' is not a subtype of type 'GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>

Tags: flutter, dart

*I am trying to show a SnackBar on my homepage since my Common.dart, but flutter send me back an error like this:*

caught Exception by `gesture`:

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
type 'LabeledGlobalKey<State<StatefulWidget>>' is not a subtype of type 'GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>'
```

**Test:** 
- I tried to replace the `showSnackbar` method with a `return` and the error stopped but the `return String` doesn't work.

Code `HomePage.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yakoa/custom_librairies/Common.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage createState() => _HomePage();
}

class _HomePage extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldkey,
      body: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Element 1",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
              buildSeparator(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
              Text("Element 1",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 35, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
              buildSeparator(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width)
            ],
          )),
      floatingActionButton: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("Click"),
        onPressed: () {
showSnackbar(_scaffoldkey,"yes");
        },
      ),
    );
```

`Common.dart`:

```
void showSnackbar(GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldKey, String text) {
  final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(text));
  scaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
}
```

Thank you,
Théo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the type of the `GlobalKey`:

```
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```